# for i in {00..03} doesn't work with nohup

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

The for loop submitted to nohup doesn't work, normally:

```
  $ for i in {00..03};do echo $i;done
  00
  01
  02
  03
```

But write these code to test.sh, nohup ./test.sh & gives following output:

```
  $ nohup ./test.sh &
  {00..03}
```

cannot produce 00 01 02 03, why ?
Ps. on debian 8 or ubuntu 15.10 ('seq -w' works)

Comment: It is working fine in my system.

Comment: which system you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu linux and place the line `#!/bin/bash` in file.

Comment: Thanks it works with #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 3):

If your file has no shebang, it depends on the shell `nohup` runs the script in. Prepend this line to the file:

```
  #!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **brace-expansion** is not a POSIX shell feature, and many system services are run in POSIX mode, this doesn't work.

The portable way to solve this for just four items is to use

```
for i in 00 01 02 03; do
  something
done
```

If you get into the habit of doing things the POSIX way you'll run into less surprises of this sort.